# How to return HTML expression from Angular method?

Tags: angular, typescript

so the title is maybe not the best...but nothing better came to my mind:

I would like to highlight search keywords on the result list...this is the reason, why I am struggeling with this issue.
CSS:

```
highlightText{
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

In Typscript:

```
myVariable = "hello world";
keyword=" bonjour";

highlightText(text: string){
   return text.replace(keyword, "<span class='highlightStyle'>"+keyword+"</span>");
}
```

In HTML:

```
<div>
    {{highlightText(myVariable)}}
</div>
```

On the screen I see the whole text..:

< span class='highlightStyle' >bonjour< /span > world

However I would really expect:
**bonjour** world

yuhhuu that's all :D

any idea?

Thanks,Csaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use a pipe - it's more performant (functions are run for each change detection cycle, while pipes only when their input arguments change)

check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highlight-pipe